# Memory leak cause of alloc, how to release the variable before function returns it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

```
-(NSString *) getSingRecord: (NSString *) getStatement{

    NSString *sql=getStatement;

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *fieldFlagI=@"0";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        //while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *fieldFlag=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            fieldFlagI=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:fieldFlag];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        statement=nil;
    }
    return fieldFlagI;
}
```

fieldFlagI is having memory leak cause I am using alloc, how do I release it before returning in function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use

```
fieldFlagI=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",fieldFlag];
```

This way you don't call `alloc` and you won't need to call `release`

Answer (score 2):

Add autorelease:

```
fieldFlagI=[[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:fieldFlag] autorelease];
```

And be sure to read Apple's memory management programming guide, or at least some tutorials about objective C's memory management.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `autorelease` it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringWithUTF8String`. This method will return autorelease object.